If you have two probabilities, how do you describe how much more likely one is than the other?
So, if I have two statistics like,
"There's a .135% chance you'll be involved in a fatal car accident if you drive while you're high and a .108% chance if you drive while you're drunk."
Are you 25% more likely to be in a fatal car accident if you drive while you're high or are you .027% more likely?
I was thinking that this means 135 out of 100000 high drivers will kill someone this year but 108 out of 100000 drunk drivers will.  That's 25% more.  But I'm not sure if it works that way.

Seemingly related

Presumably you know that it does not make any biological sense to clump together all "high"-inducing drugs together even if you leave alcohol out of that group...

Yeah @michael-lew, this stat was just active THC vs. alcohol.  I have a specific need in this case because I have someone telling me that driving while high on THC is safe because it's not like alcohol.  I was trying to figure out how to relate these stats to each other.

This is a great question. I would love a more explicit and provocative title like "Compare two percentages with a percentage?"

You just have to be careful to state what you're comparing the increase to.  You have:
$$\frac{0.135 \%}{0.108 \%} = \frac{0.00135}{0.00108} = 1.25 = 1 + 0.25 = 100 \% + 25 \%,$$
so with those probabilities stipulated, you're 25% more likely to be involved in a fatal car accident if you drive while high than if you drive while drunk.

The other way to phrase it is
You are .027 percentage points (or %pt.) more likely to be in a fatal car accident if you drive while you're high than if you drive while you're drunk.
Both are correct, at least to a careful statistician. But both sound very different to lay people, so it's just whichever way you want your statistic to lie.

This is also why election results are often expressed in "points" rather than "percents" by journalists. "Candidate A lost 5% in the last poll" is different from "Candidate A lost 5 points in the last poll"
